# Change a part of string to a variable, but its already within quotes

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i have a command like so:

```
body.style.backgroundImage = `${"url('./images/3.jpg')"}`
```

Is there a way i can change the number of the jpg using a variable despite it being encased in a ''? or do i have to replace my structure entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var num = 3
body.style.backgroundImage = `url('./images/${num}.jpg')`
```